# Search using textbox value, then displaying it in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview

Now I'm trying to make a page that supposed to display the search result in the datagrid view, the page looks like this:

here's the stored procedure

> ```
> alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[msProject_Select]
> ```
>
> ProjectCode Varchar(50)
>   AS
>   BEGIN
>         SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
  SELECT [projectCode]
        ,[projectName]
  FROM Master..[MS_Project]
  WHERE [projectCode] like '%' + @ProjectCode + '%'
  ORDER BY [projectCode] ASC
```

END

the textbox in aspx page:

```
 <td align="left" width="200px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbProjectCode" runat="server" Width="194px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
```

the search button in aspx page:

```
 <td align="center" width="25px">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/MagnifierGlass.png"
                            Width="75%" Height="75%" OnClientClick="openNewWin();return false;" />
                    </td>
```

and the datagrid in aspx page:

```
<td>
  <asp:Panel ID="PanelDGV" runat="server" Height="100%" ScrollBars="None" Width="100%">
  <asp:GridView ID="DGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
           AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
                        <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCode" HeaderText="Project Code" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" />
  <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/Edit.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CommandName="CmdSearch" HeaderText="Edit">
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
         </asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
  <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
 <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
         </asp:GridView>
     </asp:Panel>
```

how can I supposed to do it? The idea is when I type what I want then click the button, the stored procedure will run and then the result will be display in the datagrid view, so far I try with no result, anyone can help? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an event handler on the button that runs the stored procedure and binds the resulting data to the GridView.

Comment: what kind of event handler, sir? can you give some example, maybe reference?

Comment: never mind, i understand now what you mean by event handler :)